# Iterating collpasible bootstrap data table in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my static bootstrap data table that lists count of total number of fruits harvested in different months in an incremental manner into a dynamic one by using the below JSON

**JSON**

```
{
  "fruit": [
    {
      "fruitName": "All",
      "season": [
        {
          "seasonName": "All",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 200
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 200
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Sept",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Oct",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "fruitName": "Orange",
      "season": [
        {
          "seasonName": "All",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Sept",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Oct",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "fruitName": "Grapes",
      "season": [
        {
          "seasonName": "All",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Sept",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Oct",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order11" ng-repeat="item in result.fruit">
                <td>{{item.fruitName}}</td>
                <td>All</td>
                <td>200 </td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="collapse order11">
                <td></td>
                <td>Sept</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>100 </td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="collapse order11">
                <td></td>
                <td>Oct</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>100 </td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
```

The functionality of data table is that when you click on a row it expands to show the child elements butI'm not able to iterate my table using multiple `ng-repeat` as I'm using separate `<tr>` for collapse functionality.Has anyone faced same issue before please let me know..

Please find the working fiddle  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/rqok0ny4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do.

1. You need to `index` the collapsible sections so that they are unique to the row they sit under. That way you can iterate through the repeater and have a distinct section for each fruit.
2. Then repeat for each "season" in the collapsible section. You need to pivot the data on the year so that the yearly data is displayed dynamically across the columns
3. You will then need to alter the data to have a "rolled-up" total value that is displayed in the rows are collapsed or else only show the first record assuming the first record is always going to be the "All" type.
4. You will also need to force each column width to be the same (or at least consistent) across each section or it may look untidy without proper styling.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/41zpLqbr/) with some of the changes. It uses div instead of table as that is easier to create right now. You can play with the styles to make it fit your requirements.

Comment: Can you pls edit in fiddle as I've no idea how to repeat in individual `tr`

Comment: fiddle added to the answer above

Comment: thanks for the solution.I see the main rows are duplicates.Is there anyway to show only one ?

Comment: That's what I meant in #3 in the list. You could put an attribute in the JSON such as isTotal and ignore those in the repeater.

Comment: I've added a filter to eliminate the first row assuming it is always called 'All' and updated the fiddle so it now only shows the non-totaled rows